# How to fill a provided empty certificate with the necessary values from HubSpot (Like Name and Surname)?

Tags: adobe, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I have a Adobe certificate template where I want to fill the Name and surname and the course complete on the certificate with the values pulled from HubSpot by using Tray.io. Will this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would go completely away from tray.io and switch over to something like integromat/make or zapier I use integromat for data transfer into my hubspot instance and I can queue up those fields from adobe

Comment: Any tips on how you extract the data info from hubspot to an Adobe certificate. At the moment I'm using Adobe sign text tags, but I'm getting not far